# PHP Script for log in form with SQL Server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I am running a website locally. I have created a php script for a sign in form.

```
<?php

#starts a new session
session_start();

#includes a database connection
$serverName = "SQLServerNamehere"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"DatabaseNameHere", 
"UID"=>"ServerUsernameHere", "PWD"=>"ServerPasswordHere");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

#catches user/password submitted by html form
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

#checks if the html form is filled
if(empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['password'])){
echo "Fill all the fields!";
}else{

#searches for email and password in the database
$query = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Test] WHERE UserEmail(SQL Table 
column)='{$email}' AND UserPassword(SQL table column)='{$password}'";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);  

#checks if the search was made
if($result === false){
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

#checks if the search brought some row and if it is one only row
if(sqlsrv_has_rows($result) != 1){
echo "Email/password not found";
}else{

#creates sessions
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)){
$_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
$_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
$_SESSION['user'] = $row['user'];
$_SESSION['level'] = $row['level'];
}
#redirects user
header("Location: homepage.html");
}
}

?>
```

This file is called signin.php

My html login form is called signin.html:

```
<form class="login-form" action = 'signin.php' method="post">
  <input type="text" placeholder="email"/>
  <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
  <button>login</button>
</p> -->

</form>
```

Now when the user clicks the login button after entering the correct credentials i want the user to be redirected to the homepage tab but at the moment when you enter the credentials and click the login button it just displays the PHP code. I am new to this, can someone possibly explain to me how i can get this working? Thanks

Comment: Create another script, and put the following code in it: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. Run it in your browser. See the code? You have a problem with your server handlers, parsing the code as PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's displaying the PHP code, your webserver is not set up to handle PHP files.

How to do this depends on your OS and Webserver stack, but typically, you will need to install a PHP handler, and then add configurations to your webserver to tell it that when a request comes in for a PHP file, to pass that code off to the PHP application and return it as a rendered webpage.

You can refer to the PHP docs for further information:

http://php.net/manual/en/install.php